# SQL Decimal separator

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT LEFT( CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(RUNNING_BALANCe AS MONEY), 1), LEN( CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(RUNNING_BALANCe AS MONEY), 1)) - 1) 
from load_transaction_history
WHERE  [POSTED_ON] between '2008-06-10' and '2008-06-15' and account_number='12345678'
order by posted_on
```

Now the problem is that the ammounts i ger are like so 6,471,538.30 however being in Europe, i want the decimal separators like so

6.471.538,30 ...is there a way to do this is SQL...i tried copy paste in excel but formatting doesn't work.....

Answer (score 1):

For your logon in SQL server set default language to something european.

Comment: nope doesnt work..doubt it has to do with the setting in SQL2005 or my regional settings tried that...wonder if you guys know a way to convert this  results in excel,.,,as in SQL the amount is stored as somethign like this 146275.7000000

Comment: You can set Excel decimal separator to different symbol (atleast in Excel 2007). And if you're using Excel, then you could query numeric values directly, without converting them to varchar - avoids regional settings problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the locale using [this](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/set-set_21.htm)

`SET LANGUAGE British English`

Comment: it is in enlish..still same results

Comment: @Andreas: sorry what about British English

Comment: Its not the language guys...nothing to do with it,,i am sort of looking for a function in SQL

Answer (score 0):

You could always just replace them yourself:

```
SELECT LEFT( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(RUNNING_BALANCe AS MONEY), 1), '.', '$'), ',', '.'), '$', ','), LEN( CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(RUNNING_BALANCe AS MONEY), 1)) - 1)
from load_transaction_history
WHERE  [POSTED_ON] between '2008-06-10' and '2008-06-15' and account_number='12345678'
order by posted_on
```